# Splitting string field and repeating other fields in output objects

Tags: powershell, scripting, denormalization

I need to separate the following array data but can't think of a good and quick way to do it.

```
Name                              OrderGroup           OrderDate
PID365583                         FY13Q1-D             8/28/2014 12:00:00AM
PID354731,361935                  FY13Q2-D             8/28/2014 12:00:00 AM
PID354737,361937                  FY13Q3-D             11/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
PID359099,361933,363165           FY13Q4-D             11/13/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Every name that has more than one number associated with it (separated by commas) I need to move to a separate line in the array and copy the same info from the array line that it's currently in. So `PID354731,361935` would need to be broken into two lines, one for `PID354731` and one for `361935`; both would contain the same ordergroup `FY13Q2-D` and order date `8/28/2014 12:00:00 AM`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming file data:

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content $file | select -skip 1) )
{
 $Parts = $line.split(' ',3)
  foreach ($Name in $Parts[0].split(',') )
   {
     [PSCustomObject]@{
       Name = $Name
       OrderGroup = $Parts[1]
       OrderDate = [datetime]$Parts[2]
      }
   }

 }
```