# parse lines of text into two variables in powershell

Tags: arrays, parsing, powershell, csv, ip-address

I have a test file that is formatted as the following:

```
    <IPADDRESS1> # <STRINGA>
    <IPADDRESS2> # <STRINGB>
    <IPADDRESS3> # <STRINGA;STRINGB>
```

Sometimes there are multiple strings separated by a ";"

What I'd like to do in PowerShell is parse this into an array for each IP / String combo and output to CSV

Desired output:

```
    IPAddress1,STRINGA
    IPAddress2,STRINGB
    IPAddress3,STRINGA
    IPAddress3,STRINGB
```

This issue I am currently having with PowerShell is I can't get the ForEach to pass the IP Address part into a new line with the secondary string when i pipe it to split:

```
get-content C:\file.txt | %{$_ -replace " # ",""} | %{$_ -split ";"}
```

The output in this example:

```
    IPAddress1,STRINGA
    IPAddress2,STRINGB
    IPAddress3,STRINGA
    STRINGB
```

note, this is missing the IP Address for the last row.

My thoughts is that I need to read each line of text into a some sort of parsing function to  handle the address and the string and build an array in order to output this array to a csv.

Any help would be great, if there is an easier way to do this, please let me know. I'm limited to powershell.

Comment: Have a look at this answer. Very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057283/splitting-string-field-and-repeating-other-fields-in-output-objects/28057440#28057440

Comment: I think that will help, I just need to find a way to convert it into my use case.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using your test data (can't really tell if those <> are supposed to be part of the data or not):

```
$text = 
'IPADDRESS1 # STRINGA',
'IPADDRESS2 # STRINGB',
'IPADDRESS3 # STRINGA;STRINGB'

$text | foreach {
$Address,$Strings = $_.split('#').trim()
Foreach ($String in $Strings.split(';'))
 {"$Address,$String" }
}


IPADDRESS1,STRINGA
IPADDRESS2,STRINGB
IPADDRESS3,STRINGA
IPADDRESS3,STRINGB
```

Comment: Nice.  Didn't realize the `,<substitute>` was optional on the `-replace` operator.  All this time I've been passing in `''` when I just wanted to remove text.  :-)

Comment: "<" and ">" are not in the data.

Comment: Updated for new data requirements.

Comment: had to add `Foreach {$_ -replace ' # ','#'}` before to handle spaces, but this worked for me. 

Thanks!

Comment: That .trim() should have taken care of the spaces.  What version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
Get-Content C:\file.txt | % { 
    if($_ -match '<(.*?)>\s+#\s+<(.*?)>') {
        $Matches[2] -split ';' | % { "$($Matches[1]),$_" }
    } else { Write-Host "Line '$_' doesn't match regex" }
}

IPADDRESS1,STRINGA
IPADDRESS2,STRINGB
IPADDRESS3,STRINGA
IPADDRESS3,STRINGB
```